# Excel, subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba

I have read probably everysingle post on the internet but can't make it work.

I have created a form that has (1) ListBox control and (1) Excel spreadsheet control. That s it. What i am trying to accomplish is to be able to browse the excel workbooks inside the spreadsheet control.

I have the list populated already from an specific folder in the network, I was also able to dump the data to the spreadsheet control but only from the "Active Workbook. and this is the problem. I need to activate diferent workbooks as I click on the listbox. See below my code for the listbox.Click(). I am getting the error message here "Workbooks(workbooknow).Activate". i have make sure that the file extensions are correct and that the file names are correct also, confirmed with debug.

Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

```
Dim p_wsSheet As Worksheet
Dim p_rnData As Range
Dim p_owcSpread As OWC11.Spreadsheet
Dim workbooknow As String
Dim fPath As String

workbooknow = ListBox1.Text

Workbooks(workbooknow).Activate



Set p_wsSheet = ActiveSheet
Set p_rnData = p_wsSheet.Range("A1:N300")

Set p_owcSpread = Me.Spreadsheet1

With p_owcSpread
     'Populate a range.
    With .ActiveSheet
        .Range("A2:N300").Value = p_rnData.Value
    End With
     'Limit the range to be viewed in the control.
    With .ActiveWindow
        .ViewableRange = "A1:N300"
    End With
End With

Set p_owcSpread = Nothing
```

End Sub

This is how I get the List Populated in the listbox

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

```
Dim filelist() As String
Dim fname As String
Dim fnameActivation As String
Dim fPath As String
Dim I As Integer



 'define the directory to be searched for files

fPath = "X:\ESTIMATINGSOLUTIONS\"

 'build a list of the files
fname = Dir(fPath & "*.xlsx")
While fname <> ""
     'add fName to the list
    I = I + 1
    ReDim Preserve filelist(1 To I)
    filelist(I) = fname

   ' Workbooks(fname).Activate
     'get next filename
    fname = Dir()

Wend
 'see if any files were found
If I = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No files found"
    Exit Sub
End If
 'cycle through the list and add to listbox
For I = 1 To UBound(filelist)
    Me.ListBox1.AddItem filelist(I)
Next
```

End Sub

I wonder if this error message come from the " file path" at the time of making active the workbook. Any help here.

Comment: You want the input to only be `filename.filetype` so for example `C:\test.xlsx` should only be `workbooks("test.xlsx").activate`

Comment: Thank you Zerk, I can confirm when I debuged that that is exactly what workbooknow is holding. This is very weird. I have done it in different ways  but I get the same error.

Comment: I even put the file name directly on Workbooks("assistivelistening.xlsx").Activate and i get the same error. What it could be. The file exist because it is actually added to the listbox.

Comment: Sorry if this is asking an obvious question but I need to be sure. Do you have the target file open already? workbooks(x).activate only functions if it is. Otherwise do workbooks.open(x)